# JPA NamedQueries problem with nested logical operator

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, jpql

I have the following Problem. I want to filter on a column in my table to either be true or if false then only give me the entries with a date greater than xxx. So basicly return me every Customer that is a valid customer and return alle Customers that are not valid and have a activationDate greater then 3.5 years.

| name | is_customer | activation_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pete | True | 2021.02.02 |
| Sam | False | 2021.02.02 |

I tried the query inside my psql console and there everything is working fine. But when im trying to adapt it to be used with @NamedQueries in my JPA Entity the query cant be validated (neither in Intellij nor while running the code).

Query in Postgres (WORKING FINE):

```
SELECT * FROM customer c
WHERE (c.is_customer = true) OR (c.is_customer = false AND c.activation_date >  CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '3.5 years');
```

Query in Java (NOT WORKING):

```
@NamedQuery(name = CustomerBE.NAMED_QUERY,
                query = "SELECT c FROM CustomerBE c "
                       + "WHERE (c.isCustomer= true) OR (c.isCustomer= false AND c.activationDate > CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '3.5 years')"
)
```

Intellij Error: `'(', <expression> or identifier expected, got '('`

JPQL Error:

```
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT c FROM CustomerBE c WHERE (c.isCustomer= true) OR (c.isCustomer= false AND c.activationDate > CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '3.5 years']. 
[41, 297] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.
[297, 298] The query contains a malformed ending
```

I already tried adaption the bracket placement.
Did someone maybe have a simmilar problem or a workaround solution for me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok fixed it now. The Problem was the postgre Part "CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '3.5 years'" had to substitute it with :filterDate and set it through the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to put a space before the WHERE clause or else your string will not be a valid JPQL:

"SELECT c FROM CustomerBE cWHERE (c.isCustomer= true) O ..."

I'm not sure if this is the problem you reported, but it is also a problem to be fixed.